# Homemade Marinara Sauce: Shelf-Life and Reheating Question

Tags: sauce, pasta, marinara

I just made marinara sauce yesterday, sauced some pasta with some and put the rest in a mason jar. How long can I expected this to stay fresh? It's completely sealed-off in a mason jar, I used canned tomatoes and fresh ingredients to make it.

Also, was just making some fresh pasta and accidentally pre-heated all of the marinara in the microwave enough that it began steaming: can I seal-off any that I don't use and save for a later date?

For reference, Marinara and/or Tomato Sauce is not listed in the "storage guide."

Comment: Sealed and stored in the fridge?

Comment: If you've left it out it's already spoiled. If it's in the fridge then look at the link @moscafj posted.

Comment: Doesn't list anything for tomato sauce or marinara. Didn't leave it out, had it in the fridge, but heated it all up in the microwave, didn't use it all. Can I put the remainder back in the fridge?

Comment: The dupe target lists "cooked dishes", your sauce falls under them. In general, we don't repeat the same basics of food safety (including reheating, shelf life etc.) every time a person wonders about these, because the volume is easily larger than all other questions combined, and the answer boils down to a few very general rules, which are intentionaly easy to apply. If you never read those official rules, we have a summary of them under https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info.